# Slug input field checking function doesn't work properly

Tags: php, function

My slug url is made of title so I have basic Slug function and one of my own who checking slug input field is/not empty and do some action, but it doesn't work properly.. so maybe someone have some ideas what am I doing wrong?!

here is basic slug function:

```
function slug($text){ 

    // replace non letter or digits by -
    $text = preg_replace('~[^\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);

    // transliterate
    $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);

    // remove unwanted characters
    $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);

    // trim
    $text = trim($text, '-');

    // remove duplicated - symbols
    $text = preg_replace('~-+~', '-', $text);

    // lowercase
    $text = strtolower($text);

    if (empty($text)) {
      return 'n-a';
    }

    return $text;
}
```

here is function I wrote (which doesn't work properly) :

```
function filterSlug($ax, $bx){
    if(isset($_POST[$ax]) && $_POST[$ax] != ''){
        $ax = slug($ax);
    } else {
        $ax = slug($bx);
    }
    }
```

I call it out :

```
filterSlug($postSlug, $postTitle);
```

here is code I duplicate in other pages :

```
if(isset($_POST['postSlug']) && $_POST['postSlug'] != ''){
                    $postSlug = slug($postSlug);
                } else {
                    $postSlug = slug($postTitle);
                }
```

this one works correctly.

Comment: But you're not returning anything in `filterSlug`, you just change local value which is lost afterwards.

Comment: If your PHP is recent enough, I'd suggest replacing `filterSlug` with this: `$postSlug  = slug($_POST['postSlug'] ?? $postTitle);`

Answer (score 0):

You must to return something from you function:

```
function filterSlug($ax, $bx){
    if(isset($_POST[$ax]) && $_POST[$ax] != ''){ 
        $ax = slug($ax);
    } else { 
        $ax = slug($bx);
    }
    return $ax;
}
```

Comment: with return $ax; function works only if field not empty .. ?

Comment: and this line: $postSlug = slug($_POST['postSlug'] ?? $postTitle); brings to: slug function: return 'n-a';

Comment: If $ax and $bx are empty the function will return `n-a`. Try `echo filterSlug($postSlug, $postTitle);`

Comment: this should work ($postSlug = slug($postTitle);) if i left postSlug field empty, but its not working ?

Comment: your check in filterSlug function is a dynamic check: `if(isset($_POST[$ax]) && $_POST[$ax] != '')`. Try to convert in: `if(isset($_POST['postSlug']) && $_POST['postSlug'] != '')` and say me if it do the trick

Comment: the thing is for other page i need to change this line to (pageSlug), like: ( if(isset($_POST['pageSlug']) && $_POST['pageSlug'] != '')) that mean function still not working properly..

Comment: it didn't make the trick. maybe, something wrong with syntax here: $_POST[$ax] ?

Comment: @Axīc no matter with `$_POST[$ax]`… I don't know if I understand correctly you question, but I have no matter with your code, maybe some other issue passing parameters?